# XPath - assign a value to variable and use it later

Tags: variables, xpath

Does XPath supports the concept of variables?

My use case is when I need to use one long XPath expression a few times inside one experession.

For instance in XPath 1.0 (where there's no `lower-case()` function), I want to evaluate the lower case of a string and use it inside the expression. Instead of writing:

```
//*[
      contains(
           @text, 
           translate(
                'My String', 
                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
           )
      )
      and not (
           ./descendant::*[
           contains(
                @text, 
                translate(
                     'Some String', 
                     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                     'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                )
           ]
      )
 ]
```

I want to write something like:

```
 $myLowerCaseString = translate(
      'My String', 
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
 )
 //*[
      contains(
           @text, 
           $myLowerCaseString
      )
      and not (
           ./descendant::*[
           contains(
                @text, 
                $myLowerCaseString
           ]
      )
 ]
```

(NOTE: This scenario may have a different solution. and I'm looking for a general solution for scenarios that uses the same complicated String/Boolean/Node/NodeSet evaluation several times).

Answer (score 1):

Not in pure XPath 1.0, no.  You'd have to evaluate one expression, then provide the result as a variable binding to the second expression using whatever mechanism your XPath library provides.

However, duplicating the same `translate()` call several times within one expression doesn't necessarily mean it will be evaluated several times, some processors will be able to recognise that the repeated sub-expression will always yield the same result and optimise to only evaluate it once.

Comment: So... assuming I don't have access to the XPath library that compiles my XPath, I'm pretty much doomed to write ugly-long expressions...

Comment: @Elist in XPath 1.0, yes. You can sometimes work around it using `for` expressions in XPath 2.0.

Comment: OK, I'll look into switching to XPath 2.0. I'll accept the answer if no one comes up with another solution soon...